# Make entire link cell a hyperlink in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having issues with linking to another sheet within a workbook. In outlook for Mac the whole cell is clickable, but in Windows only the text is clickable. I would like the whole cell to always be clickable.

Here is my cell formula:

=HYPERLINK("#'Criteria'!A1", "Criteria")

Why would this render differently between mac and windows?

Comment: Use worksheet_selectionchange and if the cell contains a hyperlink then follow hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to get it to follow the hyperlink within that cell when you click the cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        Target.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
    End If
End Sub
```

I've uploaded the example for download here: https://app.pathio.com/bjoernstiel/Hyperlink.xlsm

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to set the WrapText property to True

`Range("A1").WrapText = True`

Answer (score 1):

This is how Windows [desktop] Excel behaves. Even a cell hyperlink (select cell, right-click, hyperlink) will only have the characters in the cell as a clickable link.

If you have no text in the cell, the entire cell will be the hyperlink. Even if you have no cell value and change only the format in a custom fashion, only the text will be a clickable hyperlink.

While you *could* use a worksheet_change event, as Jeeped described, that sounds like more of a PITA then I'd recommend.

Another workaround would be to use a shape, which is sized/placed over the boundaries of the cell, and hyperlink the shape.